# What is difference between "public float getFocalLength ()" and "public void getFocusDistances (float[] output)" in Android?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

There are two methods in android SDK docs:

```
 public float getFocalLength ()
Since: API Level 8

 public void getFocusDistances (float[] output)
Since: API Level 9
```

How to differ them?

Why the second method output an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two APIs mean different things.
The getFocalLength API tells you the distance between your lens and its focal point.
The getFocusDistances API tells you the a range of distance where your subject will be in focus if their distance is within that range.